# Gedit's LaTeX plugin opens a dialog called "Choose Master Document" each time a .tex file is opened

Tags: gedit, latex

I use gedit-latex-plugin to edit my LaTeX documents. However, each time I open a .tex or .sty file, an annoying dialog labeled "Choose Master Document" pops up, and unless I select the same file again, gedit doesn't enter "LaTeX mode".

Is there a way to disable this dialog or simply always load "LaTeX mode" when a .tex file is opened?

Comment: It seems you must have a complete Latex document, that is, the \begin{document} and \end{document} statements are present. Whenever the \begin{document} statement is missing the plugin does this.

Comment: I don't think that's it: it happens on complete, already compiled documents, and new ones alike.

Comment: [This link](http://sourceforge.net/p/gedit-latex/discussion/729150/thread/989623ec/) may be heplful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The LaTeX plugin creates a hidden file `.NAME.properties.xml` (where NAME ist replaced by your .tex file's name) in the same folder as your .tex file. This file contains the settings for the master document, and if it's found the plugin doesn't ask for a master document.

A sample file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?><properties><property key="MasterFilename" value="my_master_document.tex"/></properties>
```

There doesn't seem to be a way to switch of this behaviour.

Comment: What's weird is that it didn't used to be there...